# TypedFile inside object using Retrofit on Android

Tags: android, retrofit, paperclip

I'm developing an Android app that sends requests to a server (rails) through Retrofit.

My current issue is file upload. On server side I have paperclip to handle file upload.

I can't seem to include a TypedFile inside an object which I'd like to send as a parameter
Here is the api method I'm calling, whit its parameters

```
@Multipart
@POST("/containers/{id}/items")
void addItem(@Path("id") int id,
             @Part("item")NewItemData newItemData,
             Callback<String> callback);
```

Basically I want to post this object (containing a `TypedFile`)

```
public class NewItemData{
    String original_filename;
    String content_type;
    TypedFile file;
    String description;
    String location;
    int container_id;
    ...
}
```

**edit:**
I forgot to show you how i create the object

```
public NewItemData(Context context, String file_path){
    String mime_type = FileUtilities.getMimeType(file_path);
    String[] file_name_parts = file_path.split("/");
    String file_name = file_name_parts[file_name_parts.length-1];
    this.original_filename = file_name;
    this.full_file_path = file_path;
    this.content_type = mime_type;
    File file_tmp = new File(file_path);
    this.file = new TypedFile("application/octet-stream", file_tmp);
    this.description = "";
    this.location = "";
}
```

**end edit**

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: retrofit.converter.ConversionException: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2
```

And this is the object NewItemData converted to json

```
{"original_filename":"IMG_20150121_221732.jpg","content_type":"image/jpeg","description":"","file":{},"location":"","container_id":0}
```

As you can see the "file" field is empty, so I assume that the error above is referring to the fact that "file" => {} instead of the binary file

What I've tried so far hasn't worked, so my questions are:

- is possible to post a "wrapper" object in multipart mode?
- if so, what annotation should I write and where?
- should i implement a custom serializer?

If you need additional info, just ask
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

When you create the restAdapter Instance, just add this line to add a converter **.addConverterFactory( GsonConverterFactory.create())** like below

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(RestConnection.BASE_URL_MULTIMEDIA)
                .addConverterFactory( GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
```